# PPTP unable to connect via MikroTik after its reconfiguration

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, pptp, mikrotik-routeros

My home laptop(s) are configured to use PPTP and that initially worked well (see `1`). After reconfiguration of my home connection, any laptop is unable to complete its PPTP connection (see `2`), hanging after initial authentication at remote endpoint, throwing error **806** upon timeout. The same PPTP connections still work well if these laptops connect to internet anywhere else (or via mobile phone) (see `3`).

[image: 3 scenarios of the problem]

The reconfiguration was needed due to poor stability of Huawei optical modem/router provided by the ISP. They advised me to lift any work off this device and give it to the MikroTik. They remotely switched their Huawei router into bridge mode and I did reset MikroTik into factory config, then added PPP module and moved PPPoE endpoint there, and all that works.

But as you can see, this new infrastructure config is no longer transparent to PPTP connections of laptops. Even if I temporarily disable MikroTik's firewall (at least I believe) by adding and enabling rules `1` and `2` (they allow everyting, no conditions given):

Note: [image: Mikrotik's Firefall disabled if rules 1 and 2 are enabled].
PPTP service ports (on `Service Ports` tab above) are enabled, too.

The only NAT rule is the default one: `add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" ipsec-policy=out,none out-interface-list=WAN` and `WAN` interface list consists of `ether1` (as default uplink) and `PPPoE` (added by me).
.

- What else can I do to make PPTP go through via this router normally as before?

Comment: What NAT rules do you have (`/ip firewall nat export`)? What do you see while running a packet capture (`/tool sniffer`) – is there anything that reaches the router through the LAN interface but doesn't leave it through the PPP interface?

Comment: I'm guessing the last item in your filter rules is a DROP.. if so, you actually want those first two rules on, because those are what is allowing your traffic through in the first place.

Comment: @user1686 – question updated, thank you. I'll need to check the sniffer output... is there a hint how can I effectively set its capture filters to get only most informative results?

Comment: @Karu – I see your point but the PPTP is not working even if rules 1 and 2 are active. And your guess is correct, the rest of the rules are default (defconf).

Comment: @miroxlav: Due to it being PPTP, you'll need two separate captures, one for the control channel (`/tool sniffer quick ip-protocol=tcp port=1723`) and one for the data channel (`/tool sniffer quick ip-protocol=gre`, note GRE has no ports)... though, alternatively, you could just filter by the VPN server's IP address and that way get everything at once. In general I suspect that GRE is the issue (e.g. maybe it's not being NATed correctly).